# How to upload Application on itunes using application loader

Tags: iphone, code-signing, app-store-connect

I want to upload my application to iTunes Connect using application loader. For that I have created distribution profile according to client bundle id but when I build it, it gives an error

> Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Also, when I upload the build in Application Loader under the processing in iTunes Connect, I face an error given as below. please give me the detail to solve this problem.

> ERROR -- "Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate."

So I searched on google to solve this error and according to that checked my bundle id name of app and it is correct

So please, can any one give the proper solution on this error.

Comment: There are numerous versions of this question: [search stackoverflow!](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=The+signature+was+invalid%2C+or+it+was+not+signed+with+an+Apple+submission+certificate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use your client's distribution profile when signing the app. Your distribution profile for the app doesn't match the signing identity.

Go to provisioning profile and get the correct certificate.